# Flutter iOS flutter_swipe_action_cell not updating UI after deleting cell

Tags: json, flutter, listview

I have a `ListView` containing 5 elements in the following order:

- Section Header
- Valid Item 0
- Valid Item 1
- Section Header
- Invalid Item 0

When I swipe to delete `Valid Item 0`, the `ListView` length becomes 4 instead of 5 (as expected), the UI appears in the order below, with only 3 items. I have also determined that each element in the `ListView.builder`, is being returned correctly (in the order above, except for `Valid Item 0`, as expected). Each Widget is being build as expected.

- Section Header
- Section Header
- Invalid Item 0

The UI appears correctly until I call `setState(() {})`. Once it is called, `Valid Item 1` is removed from the UI, but not the data source. If I switch the current display to a different `Scaffold` (as shown in the video below), then switch back, the UI shows correctly again. Strange.

Using the [flutter_swipe_action_cell](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_swipe_action_cell) package, I have added a delete button that appears when the cell is swiped to the left.
I followed this example:

```dart
SwipeAction(
  title: "delete",
  onTap: (CompletionHandler handler) async {           
    /// await handler(true) : will delete this row
    /// And after delete animation, setState will called to 
    /// sync your data source with your UI

    await handler(true);
    list.removeAt(index);
    setState(() {});
  },
  color: Colors.red
)
```

With this code:

```dart
SwipeAction(
  icon: Container(
    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 4),
    child: const Icon(
      Icons.delete,
      size: 30,
    )
  ),
  title: "Delete",
  performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe: true,
  onTap: (CompletionHandler handler) async {
    print("Delete Profile (valid @ ${index - 1})");
    await handler(true);
    (data["valid"] as List).removeAt(index - 1);
    setState(() {});
  },
  color: Colors.red
)
```

This is a recording of my issue:

[image: Screen Recording]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out myself after several hours of trial and error.
The *key* component here is literally `key`. I didn't realize the purpose of the key initially. It seems to be used to coordinate which cell is being deleted on the UI with its corresponding data. The `key` for each `SwipeActionCell` should reference the exact same data child which will be deleted.

```dart
SwipeActionCell(
  key: ObjectKey(data["valid"]![privateIndex]),
  ...
)
```

where `privateIndex` is the index for the list item in that section, ignoring any section headers and previous sections. Eg:

```
1. Section Header    listIndex: 0    privateIndex: N/A
2. Valid Item 0      listIndex: 1    privateIndex: 0
3. Valid Item 1      listIndex: 2    privateIndex: 1
4. Section Header    listIndex: 3    privateIndex: N/A
5. Invalid Item 0    listIndex: 4    privateIndex: 0
```

and where `data` is:

```dart
Map<String,List<dynamic>> data = {
  "valid": [
    {"title":"Valid Item 0"},
    {"title":"Valid Item 1"}
  ],
  "invalid": [
    {"title":"Invalid Item 0"}
  ]
}
```